# Apache web server generated CSR not accepted by bigrock.in

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, google-compute-engine, csr

I have generated a csr from apache web server on google cloud compute engine.i have followed following steps below:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout yourdomain.key -out yourdomain.csr
```

referred with this link https://in.godaddy.com/help/apache-generate-csr-certificate-signing-request-5269

Every-time i submit csr to get the error: Domain name in the csr doesnt match, the domain name of the purchased order.
I have contacted bigrock support many times, every time they said you have generated for wwww.yourdomain.co, and it should be yourdomain.com. But i have generated with yourdomain.co.

Please help!!!

Comment: We need more details, like the URL to the server and its X.509 certificate. Also see [How do you sign Certificate Signing Request with your Certification Authority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21340898/608639) and [How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10175812/608639) It provides a lot of background information on X.509 server certificates, and where the various rules come from.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , what is your domain name ???? I know you cannot disclose fully , but tell the format . Secondly , go here and check what your CSR contains https://www.sslshopper.com/csr-decoder.html . Check if all values were correctly filled by your or not . I have myself created CSRs on Google Compute Engine , and never faced any such problem . If you domain name is www.abc.co , it should be abc.co and if domain name is www.abc.com , it should be abc.com . And are you sure it is wwww.youdomain.com ??? wwww !!!!

Comment: thanks for the response, it was a stupid mistake i made, its solved now.

Comment: What was the mistake ?